Decode Elliptic Curve Point
I have a Point on the elliptic curve that I call G.
X:55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240
Y:32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424

I also have an integer called K
K: 4

The product of these two is P.
P = K * G
X:103388573995635080359749164254216598308788835304023601477803095234286494993683
Y: 37057141145242123013015316630864329550140216928701153669873286428255828810018

I want to get K using P and G: K = P / G. I tried that at first, but realized this is not a simple multiplication that could be undone by division. But logically, I think that it should be possible to calculate K from the fixed point G and the product P.

If you assume that $K$ is the secret and that $P$ is the public key in ECDSA then you are literally asking to derive the secret used in Elliptic Curve Cryptography with only the public key and $G$ as part of the domain parameters. If you know that $K$ is small then you can obviously just try small values of $K$ until you get $P$ as output, but I guess that  is not what you're asking.

The question is about the Discrete Logarithm Problem. Using a standard notation, it's finding unknown integer $k$ given $P$ and $G$ with $P=[k]G$, which can be defined as
$$[k]G=\underbrace{G+G+\cdots+G}_{k\text{ terms}}$$
That's enough to find a small $k$ like $k=4$ in the question, by trying successive values. And it's easy to check a guess of $k$, even if it's very large, using this equivalent definition
$$[k]G=\begin{cases}\mathcal O\text{ (the neutral/point at infinity)}&\text{if }k=0\\G&\text{if }k=1\\Q+Q\text{ with }Q=[k/2]G&\text{if }k\ge2\text{ and }k\text{ is even}\\Q+G\text{ with }Q=[k-1]G&\text{if }k\ge3\text{ and }k\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$
For standard large-enough prime order elliptic curve groups such as secp256k1 (which, it turns out, is used in the question), for any two points $P$ and $G$ on the curve (other than the neutral $\mathcal O$), there indeed is a well-defined smallest strictly positive integer $k$ such that $P=[k]G$. We know algorithms (Baby-Step/Giant-Step, Pollard's kangaroo) to find $k$ with in the order of a few times $\sqrt k$ point additions. Thus the problem is tractable on a PC for $k$ of up to 22 decimal digits, give or take.
But we know nothing better on the kinds of computer currently available, and difficulty more than triples for each additional decimal digit of $k$. For random point $P$, $k$ is typically 77-digits, thus the problem is believed currently intractable.
We do have algorithms with cost polynomial in $\log k$ that could run on hypothetical Cryptographically Relevant Quantum Computer. That motivates post-quantum cryptography to develop other cryptosystems not based on the hardness of the DLP.
